# Function to list posts from current post's category fails in WP 3.8

Tags: categories, functions

**I have this function in my child theme's functions.php**, whose simple aim is to list a number of posts, only from the category of the current post, but not the current post itself.

It was working fine until tonight, when **it started listing posts from *all* categories**, not just the current post's category.

The *only* change I had made to my site was to update it to WordPress version 3.8.  I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it, but I thought it might, since I have a "cloned" site which is still running WordPress 3.7.1, and the *exact* same function on that site works, doing exactly what I want it to, i.e., it lists a number of posts, *only* from the category of the current post, but not the current post itself.

Here's the function:

```
<?php
function list_posts_from_current_category() {
if(is_single()){
$cat_ID = get_the_category($post->ID);
$cat_ID = $cat_ID[0]->cat_ID;
$this_post = get_the_ID();
$PostsPerPage = 5;
query_posts(array('cat' => $cat_ID, 'post__not_in' => array($this_post), 'posts_per_page' => $PostsPerPage, 'orderby' => 'rand'));
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$ThisPermalink = get_permalink();
$ThisTitle = get_the_title();
echo '<a href="'.$ThisPermalink.'">'.$ThisTitle.'</a><br />';
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
}
}
add_action('do_my_list', 'list_posts_from_current_category');
?>
```

It's added to the child theme's content.php in the usual manner:

```
<?php do_action('do_my_list'); ?>
```

Like I say, it all works as intended in WP 3.7.1, but has somehow come a cropper in WP version 3.8, listing posts from *all* categories.

Does anyone know what can be wrong with it?

Comment: What does `$cat_ID` variable contain? Have you tried to `var_dump` it?

Answer (score 0):

I never found out what stopped the function from working with WP 3.8, but I found that this variant of it does work - and I have no idea why:

```
<?php
function list_posts_from_current_category() {
if(is_single()){
$tempArray = get_the_category($post->ID);
$FirstCatName = $tempArray[0]->slug;
$this_post = get_the_ID();
$PostsPerPage = 5;
query_posts(array('category_name' => $FirstCatName, 'post__not_in' => array($this_post), 'posts_per_page' => $PostsPerPage, 'orderby' => 'rand'));
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
$ThisPermalink = get_permalink();
$ThisTitle = get_the_title();
echo '<a href="<a href="#">ThisPermalink</a>">'.$ThisTitle.'</a><br />';
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
}
}
add_action('do_my_list', 'list_posts_from_current_category');
?>
```